# How to get req.user in POST request using passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a problem getting the username from POST request.
It did work with get requests.

Example: (works)

```
app.get('/images', function(req, res){
console.log(req.user)
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render('images',{ data: {user: req.user, message: req.flash('loginMessage') }} )
    }
    else {res.redirect('/login')}
});
```

Example: (Works)

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
          successRedirect : '/', // redirect to the secure profile section
          failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
          failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }),
      function(req, res) {
          if (req.body.remember) {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
          } else {
            req.session.cookie.expires = false;
          }
      res.redirect('/');
  });
```

local-login strategy: (I am using mySQL)

```
passport.use(
    'local-login',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
            }

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);
        });
    })
);
```

But this POST request I get undefined !

```
app.post('/postAlarms',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.user)
    });
```

The AJAX request is:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://"+ip+":3000/postAlarms",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                arr: ids
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
          });
```

What should I do to get the username of the user that POST data to server?

Comment: are you using body-parser?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this:
app.post('/postAlarms',urlencodedParser, function(req, res){..}
But it did not work

Comment: did you try console.log(req.body.user)?

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Yes, also undefined

Comment: I am logged in, when I go to localhost:3000/images, I get the user name, but when sending the POST request I get undefined

Comment: any workaround ? same issue?