# Passport.js get currently logged in user through Post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, passport.js

I am running into an issue with Passport.js in which I want to get the currently logged in users information from a Post request and process some stuff. When I console.log(req.user) it comes up as 'undefined'. The set up and authentication all works, I can also retreive user's info using a Get request as seen from the first code snippet.

```
router.get('/', function(req , res){
    console.log("The current logged in user is: " + req.user.first_name);
    res.render('index.ejs' , {
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

^ returns user's name as expected

```
router.post('/testPost' ,function(req , res){
    console.log("The current logged in user is: " + req.user);
    res.json({
        status: "success" 
     });
});
```

^returns undefined even when the user is logged in.

I have seen the same question raised here [How to get req.user in POST request using passport js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620680/how-to-get-req-user-in-post-request-using-passport-js) two years ago but there was no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the user might not be logged in at the time you're checking it.

To ensure that a user is logged in when accessing a route you should have a middleware that checks it for you.

You can write it as a separate module and import it in every single one of your routes if it's required.

> The module:

```
module.exports = {
    EnsureAuthenticated: (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    }
};
```

> The routes:

```
//Destructuring | EnsureAuth Function
const {
    EnsureAuthenticated
} = require('../path/to/the/module');


//You should get your user here
router.get('/', EnsureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
console.log(req.user)
});
```